# Run javascript function on iOS UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to run a javascript from a UIWebView. The javascript function I want to run is the one below

```
function SelectAnimal() {
var sel = document.getElementById('Animals');
var val = document.getElementById('AnimalToFind').value;
for(var i = 0, j = sel.options.length; i < j; ++i) {
    if(sel.options[i].innerHTML === val) {
       sel.selectedIndex = i;
       break;
    }
}
```

}

I know you can execute javascript in UIWebView using

```
(NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

So i form the javascript string as

```
NSString *str = @"function SelectAnimal() {\
    var sel = document.getElementById('Animals');\
    var val = document.getElementById('AnimalToFind').value;\
    for(var i = 0, j = sel.options.length; i < j; ++i) {\
        if(sel.options[i].innerHTML === val) {\
            sel.selectedIndex = i;\
            break;\
        }\
    }\
}";
```

and run the javascript as

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];
```

But this doesnt seem to work. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your javascript is only defining the function, but never calling it.

Try changing to:

```
NSString *str = @"function SelectAnimal() {\
    var sel = document.getElementById('Animals');\
    var val = document.getElementById('AnimalToFind').value;\
    for(var i = 0, j = sel.options.length; i < j; ++i) {\
        if(sel.options[i].innerHTML === val) {\
            sel.selectedIndex = i;\
            break;\
        }\
    }\
}\
selectAnimal();";
```

Comment: That was really dumb. I'm almost embarrassed. Thanks buddy!